# C++ Save dialog

Tags: c++, streaming, fwrite, streamwriter

I call a save dialog to save a xml file (ex: a.xml), then save a clone of it(ex: a_clone.xml) to other location silently. But it only work for a.xml file.
This my code for save dialog:

```
string Savefilename(char *filter = "Mission Files (*.mmf)\0*.mmf", HWND owner = NULL){
    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    char fileName[MAX_PATH] = "";
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hwndOwner = owner;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = filter;
    ofn.lpstrFile = fileName;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = "";
    ofn.lpstrInitialDir ="Missions\\";

    string fileNameStr;
    if ( GetSaveFileName(&ofn) )
    fileNameStr = fileName;

    return fileNameStr;
}
```

Can anyone help me please!

Comment: What do you mean "it only work for a.xml file" ? What's not working? Where's the code where you're saving the clone?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I mean only "a.xml" file is saved but "a_clone.xml" is not.

Comment: Where's the code where you're saving the clone? How can we say what's wrong with it without seeing it?

Comment: Are you looking for `CopyFile(source, destination, fail_if_exists)`?

Comment: Here code to save text to clone file:
std::ofstream myfile ("GameSDK/libs/a_clone.xml");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
   myfile<<"Template: ";
   myfile<<writeNote;
   myfile.close();
  }

Comment: I just test with CopyFile(filePath, "test.xml", false);
but it does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

`CopyFile` is a simple function and generally reliable. It fails here probably because target directory does not exit, or because you don't have write access to target directory. It's the same with `std::ofstream myfile` you are probably not checking for errors.

Make sure target directory exists. Give the full pathname to destination file. Make sure you have access to target directory.

Note, "c:\program files" etc. are protected directories, you need admin access to copy to these directories.

You can also check for errors:

```
SetLastError(0);

CopyFile(source, destination, FALSE);

DWORD error = GetLastError();
if (error)
{
    char buf[255];
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, error, 0, buf, 255, 0);
    cout << "error: " << error << ", " << buf << endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the problem comes from target directory, because before save dialog opened I have tried to write a text file to target directory successfully